# Show that the family of a subset of $X$ is a basis for some topology?

Tags: general-topology

> > Question :
> >
> > Let $p$ be a prime fixed number in $\mathbb Z $. For each integer $ a > 0$ , define $U_a(n) = \{ n + \lambda p^a | \lambda \in \mathbb Z \}$. Show that $\{ U_a(n) \}$ is a basis for some topology on $\mathbb Z$ .

we shall show that each $k \in U_a(n) \cap U_b(m)$, then $ \exists \ \ {U_c(l)}$ such that $ k \in U_c(l) \subset U_a(n) \cap U_b(m)$

if $k \in U_a(n) \cap U_b(m)$, then $k = n + \lambda p^a = m + \lambda' p^b$.

Please tell me how to proceed further to get $U_c(l)$. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Keep $a \leq b.$  If   $n + \lambda p^a = m + \lambda' p^b$ then $m-n= p^a (\lambda' p^{b-a}-\lambda)$ for $\lambda',\lambda \in \mathbb Z$.

Now if $U_a(n) \cap U_b(m) \neq \phi$ then we must have  $m=kp^a+n$ and then $m+ \lambda' p^b= n+(k+\lambda' p^{b-a})p^a$ for $k,\lambda' \in \mathbb Z$ and at last:$$U_b(m) \subseteq  U_a(n)$$